# Interweaving vector of binary representations in C++

Tags: c++, templates, binary

I have a templated function in C++ called weave which takes two unsigned chars and interweaves their binary expansions and returns a unsigned short.  It can also take two unsigned shorts and interweaves their binary expansions to return an unsigned long. Here is what I wrote:

```
template<class Typeout, class Typein>
Typeout weave(Typein lhs,Typein rhs)
{
//Need to check that Typeout contains enough storage to contain 2*Typein:
assert(sizeof(Typeout)>=2*sizeof(Typein));

Typeout weaved = 0;
for(int k=0;k<sizeof(Typein)*8;k++)
{
    //weave in the kth element of rhs and lhs.
    weaved |=(Typeout(rhs & (Typein)(1<<k)) << k)| (Typeout(lhs & (Typein)(1<<k)) << (k+1));
}
return weaved;
};
```

Now I'm having trouble with weaving together vectors.  I want to write a function called weave that given a vector of chars interweaves all of their binary expansions and returns this. For instance given a vector of unsigned chars of length 4 it should interweave their binary expansions and return a representation of this.  I want this to work for vectors of chars of length greater than 8 so I can no longer keep them in a unsigned long long. I guess I need to return a vector?? But I'm not sure how to cut the resulting binary expansion up.

I'm new to C++ so please feel free to correct the code or give me advice on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should separate the problem down into two distinct pieces: a `class` that represents bitwise access to an arbitrary memory region, and your algorithm that uses that class's interface.  As the former should be like `std::vector<bool>`, you could simply write code to populate a `vector<bool>` given a `void*` and a count of bits or bytes.  This would involve potentially unnecessary copies to/from the vector's heap-allocated memory - reimplement with the data internal to the class if desired.  If this comment's too vague to help, do let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do I need a class to represent the bitwise access because I can already do bitwise operations straight with the types char, short, long?  Do you mean a class to turn a char into a vector<bool> of length 8 and work with that? The trouble is I need to do this weaving very efficiently.

Comment: @alext87: yes, you can already do bitwise operations on char, short, long, but doesn't a solution require extending this to larger blocks (i.e. 20 bytes, 300 bytes)?  All I'm saying is that you can either separately solve the problem of bitwise operations on larger blocks then use your existing algorithm, OR you can make your algorithm much more complex by having it embed all the complexities of treating larger memory blocks: that's going to be harder to get and keep right, but *might* give extra optimisation opportunities.

Comment: If you need really high efficiency, I'd recommend ditching the constant bitshifting and precomputing a table so you can simply use an 8-bit character's worth of bits as an index into a 16-bit pre-bit-split value, then merge these.  For example, say the bits in the inputs are abcdefgh and ijklmnop, you'd index into a table that mapped abcdefgh to 0a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h and ijklmnop to 0i0j0k0l0m0n0o0p, then bitshift one across by one bit and OR.  Do this for each byte as you step along the input data, then special-case the handling of any odd less-than-8-bit input segment at the end.

Comment: (And if you want a funny tip: if you'd phrased this as a make-believe interview question, you'd have had 10 answers by now, some with working code - SO is a funny place ;-)).

Comment: Avoid vector<bool>, its broken. And don't follow Tony's comments on optimization, first design your algorithm, then optimize after profiling, but you'll see that most of the time it will already meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think i got your question wrong (frankly I still can't say exactly **where** is the actual question in your post). If the question is "what I should take as parameters and what type should I return?", maybe you should have a `const T*` or `const std::vector<T>&` parameter for input and another for output instead of returning, this would avoid allocated-memory ownership problems.

```
// base case, weave two 8 bit into a 16 bit word.
uint16_t weave(uint8_t a, uint8_t b) {
    uint16_t x = a, y = b;
    x = (x | (x << 4)) & 0x0F0F;
    x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x3333;
    x = (x | (x << 1)) & 0x5555;

    y = (y | (y << 4)) & 0x0F0F;
    y = (y | (y << 2)) & 0x3333;
    y = (y | (y << 1)) & 0x5555;

    return x | (y << 1);
}

// most useful way in my opinion
// weave bits from two arrays 'a' and 'b' of size n
// into a pre-allocated vector 'out'
void weave(const char* a, const char* b, char* out, size_t n) {
    uint16_t* ret = (uint16_t*) out;

    for(size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        ret[i] = weave(a[i], b[i]);
    }
}

// template version, for those that like sugar
template<typename OUT, typename IN>
OUT weave(IN a, IN b, size_t n = 1) {
    OUT out;
    weave((char*) &a, (char*) &b, (char*) &out, sizeof(IN)*n);
    return out;
}
```

**DONT** forget to add checks, asserts, etc if this goes into production code.

Comment: I don't think this is doing quite what I need. You are taking two arrays of the same length and interweaving each corresponding element in turn.  However, I have one array of length n and I want to interweave all the elements together. Does that make sense?  Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't understand your question and I still don't. Can you please edit it to add a section **clarification** below the original question please?